# Lottie player do not update the underlying animation when src attribute is changed at run time?

Tags: web-component, lottie, lit-html

I was using lottie player for animated sticker on my PWA app.
Now at run time when I change the src attribute of lottie player, it do not reloads a new animation. `<lottie-player src=${state.url}  background="transparent"  speed="1"  style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"  loop  autoplay></lottie-player>`
is there a way to force this animation to reload by changing the attribute ?

I am using lit-html as my templating library and custom framework for creating web components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lottie web player requires [a programmatic `load` method call](https://docs.lottiefiles.com/lottie-player/components/lottie-player/usage#lottie-player) to change the animation. Their api doesn't update the animation based on a runtime `src` property change.

Lit-html and web components are not required to answer the question, but I can provide a code sample using `lit` to show a working example.

Example changing animation of Lottie web player: https://lit.dev/playground/#gist=4569b4b023db7014d45112679059296b

See below for a minimal answer.

```js
class ExampleChangingAnimation extends LitElement {
  /**
   * Get the rendered Lottie player element
   */
  get lottiePlayer() {
    return this.shadowRoot.querySelector('lottie-player');
  }

  /**
   * changeAnimation gets the new animation src string and loads
   * it onto the Lottie web player.
   */
  changeAnimation () {
    // Get new animation to load.
    const newAnimation = "...animation url...";

    // Load the new animation on the lottie player element.
    this.lottiePlayer.load(newAnimation)
  }

  render () {
    return html`
      <lottie-player></lottie-player>
      <button @click=${this.changeAnimation}>Change Animation</button>
    `;
  }
}
```